# Float two anchors without specifiying width and have equal margin/padding between them

Tags: css

I am working with a design that was setup under the assumption that the two anchors would have the same text and I am having issues remedying the spacing between them automatically if one of the buttons width changes.

I setup a fiddle here showing the issue = http://jsfiddle.net/nopL10w6/

HTML

```
<div class="clear-after row">
 <a class="toggle-details">
   <span>
     Details
   </span>
</a>
<a class="button" href="#">
  Register
</a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
      X
    </span>
  </a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
     Y
    </span>
  </a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
      Z
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="clear-after row">
 <a class="toggle-details">
   <span>
     Details
   </span>
</a>
<a class="button" href="#">
  Register
</a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
      X
    </span>
  </a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
     Y
    </span>
  </a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
      Z
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="clear-after row">
 <a class="toggle-details">
   <span>
     Details
   </span>
</a>
<a class="button" href="#">
  Not Register
</a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
      X
    </span>
  </a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
     Y
    </span>
  </a>
<a class="icon">
    <span class="hidden-label">
      Z
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.clear-after:after {
clear: both;
content: "";
display: block;
}

.row{
padding: 15px 0;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.toggle-details {
display: block;
height: 0;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 100px;
}

.toggle-details span {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: normal;
color: #4d4d4d;
background: #b10816;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
padding: 8px 12px;
color: #b10816;
background: #e6e6e6;
}

a.button {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: normal;
color: #4d4d4d;
background: #b10816;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
padding: 8px 12px;
float: right;
}

.icon {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Notice that the Details & Register anchors look great, while the longer 'Not Register' would require increasing the margin-right to have it look evenly spaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are floating one button to position it, and the other you are using margin to position it.

If you remove the `.toggle-details` margin, and instead float it's child span, it resolves your issue:

```
.toggle-details {
    /*
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    */
}

.toggle-details span {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    background: #b10816;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    color: #b10816;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    float: right; /* Added */
}

a.button {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    background: #b10816;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px; /* Added */
}
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nopL10w6/1/)

---

Alternatively, you could simplify things if you wanted to tweak your css and create more standard styles. Here is an example I made:

```
.button,
a.button {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: #b10816;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.button-primary {
  background: #b10816;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
```

Also, update your html:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="toggle-details button">
        Details
    </a>
    <a class="button button-primary" href="#">
        Register
    </a>
</div>
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0y823xgv/)

The `.pull-right` class can be used to float everything all at once instead of individually floating each element.